# Execution flow for innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

To better understand my problem here is a short example,
I have following as my HTML,

```
<div id="parent">
</div>
```

Here is my JavaScript function that I'm calling on page load,

```
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
    function myFun(parent){
                parent.innerHTML += "<ul>";
                parent.innerHTML += "<li>Hello</li>";
                parent.innerHTML += "</ul>";
            }
```

I'm expecting to receive output as,

```
<div id="parent">
   <ul>
      <li>Hello</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

But instead I'm receiving below output,

```
<div id="parent">
       <ul></ul>
          <li>Hello</li>

    </div>
```

As you can see the "ul" tag is not enclosing the "li" tag.
I know I can use `appendChild` for my problem but I'm really curious why this is happening. Any ideas??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can't remember why but you should build all the html in one string and then append it only one time.

Comment: When you set the innerHTML to `'<ul>'`, the browser has to close the tag to create the element, so it becomes  `'<ul></ul>'`. When you then append an *li*, the browser must resort to error correction because the *li* must be in a *ul* or *ol*. So it might put it in the preceding one, or create a new one. As Nathan says, build a complete string of valid HTML and insert that.

Comment: You will understand things much better if you do NOT think of `.innerHTML` as a string.  Instead, there's a getter and setter function behind it.  Everytime you assign to it, it tries to parse everything you have into fully formed HTML and insert that into the DOM.  Everytime you read from it, it takes that part of the DOM and generates HTML that describes it.  Thus, you can only have fully formed HTML ever in `.innerHTML`.  So, if you're going to build up a string of HTML in multiple pieces, you must do that in a temporary variable and only assign it to `.innerHTML` when it is fully formed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same result would happen if you left off your addition of `</ul>` entirely. The `<ul>` tag got closed when you did the first append to `innerHTML` to keep the code valid.  If you assembled the string as a variable and appended it once, it would work:

```
var tmp = "<ul>";
tmp += "<li>Hello</li>";
tmp += "</ul>";
parent.innerHTML = tmp;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the '{ul}' you added the string had the browser automatically add in '{/ul}' so that the statement made sense. Then the next line added '{li}hello{/li}' which was fine. And then the browser rejected '{/ul}' afterwards because since the ul was already closed, it was meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

I did some experiments and this is what I came up with,
When I write, `parent.innerHTML += "<ul>";` the browser detects that there is no ending tag and thus adds "" as an error correction.
When the browser comes up with `'parent.innerHTML += </ul>'` it sees that there is no starting tag and hence ignores it.

Answer (score 0):

If you try the following code, you will not see that problem.

```
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
function myFun(parent){
            var html = "<ul>";
            html  += "<li>Hello</li>";
            html  += "</ul>";

            parent.innerHTML += html ;
        }
```

Because of the forgiving nature of browsers towards html, when you add just <ul> to innerHTML, it is adding <ul></ul> (in other words, a valid element). Then you are adding <li>Hello</li>, which is ok. The final </ul> is ignored by the browser because it does not see the need.